# Replace values in multiple columns based on value of one column

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe with multiple columns (around 320)

I have to find keyword `baz` in col `A`. in case the `baz` is found, then replace the existing value in all columns listed in the list `columns_for_replacement` with None

```
columns_for_replacement = ["B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
```

I am trying to modify the below code to do the same:

```
for i in columns_for_replacement:
    df = df.withColumn(i,when((col(i)=='baz'),None).otherwise(col(i)))
```

The above code works only for the specific column which is not my expected requirement.

Base dataframe:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   
baz abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
baz abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
def abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
baz abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
map abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
baz abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
noo abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

Expected dataframe:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   
baz                                 abc
baz                                 abc
def abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
baz                                 abc
map abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
baz                                 abc
noo abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to use column `A` in the when condition, not column `i`:

```
columns_for_replacement = ["B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]

for i in columns_for_replacement:
    df = df.withColumn(i, when((col("A")=='baz'), lit(None)).otherwise(col(i)))
```

Another way to do this would be to do a `select`:

```
columns_for_replacement = ["B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]

df2 = df.select([
    when((col("A")=='baz'), lit(None)).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c)
    if c in columns_for_replacement 
    else col(c)
    for c in df.columns
])
```

Comment: I bet the 2nd approach is more efficient too, based on the Note in the docs for [DataFrame.withColumn()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html): _This method introduces a projection internally. Therefore, calling it multiple times, for instance, via loops in order to add multiple columns can generate big plans which can cause performance issues and even StackOverflowException. To avoid this, use select() with the multiple columns at once._

Answer (score 1):

You need to check column `A` :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.select(
    col("A"),
    *[F.when(F.col("A") == "baz", F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in columns_for_replacement],
    col("J")
)

df1.show()

#+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+
#|  A|   B|   C|   D|   E|   F|   G|   H|   I|  J|
#+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+
#|baz|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|abc|
#|baz|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|abc|
#|def| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc|abc|
#|baz|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|abc|
#|map| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc|abc|
#|baz|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|abc|
#|noo| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc| abc|abc|
#+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+
```

Or more generic to avoid select each column other than in the list to replace:

```
df1 = df.select(
    *[F.when(F.col("A") == "baz", F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.col(c)).alias(c) for c in columns_for_replacement],
    *[F.col(c) for c in df.columns if c not in columns_for_replacement]
).toDF(*df.columns)
```